# Django Rest Framework: Create / Update by id, output dictionary

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have a django-rest-framework model viewset (for tests) that is using a serialize like this:

```
class ProcessSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Process.draft_model
        fields = ['id', 'name']


class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    process = ProcessSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = ConfigurationTest
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'process',
        ]
```

This works great when retrieving tests, but doesn't work for creation / updates, where I would ideally like to just provide the ID with a request like this:

```
{
  process: 1
  name: 'A new test'
}
```

When sending that request to the server I get an error like `Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int`

**What I tried:**

- Have `process` and `process_id` as included fields and just sending `process_id` in a POST request. In that case I get an error like `process_id cannot be null`, which is plain confusing.
- Use a different serializer for the `create` action, that uses `process` as a plain PrimaryKeyRelatedField without a nested serializer. This works nicely for getting the request, but also obviously means the server reponse to that POST request doesn't include the nicely nested serializer.

**Models for reference**

```
class ConfigurationTest(...):
    name = CharField(max_length=120)
    process = ForeignKey(Process)

class Process(...):
    name = CharField(max_length=120)
```

Comment: Can you add the models.py ? It's also not clear to me since you want to provide process id but you defined the field as read only.

Comment: 1. To my knowledge, unless you provide a way to update, you should make nested serializers read_only. If I make this not read_only, what data should I send in a POST request?

2. models.py is not very interesting, they are as you would expect, I added them.

Comment: I tried a bit more around and updated the answer. Thanks for the idea :)

Comment: Just to be clear: are you trying to create both a Test and a Process at the same time OR you want to create a Test and match it to an existing process ? In both cases, I believe you'll need to override create()/update() methods of your TestSerializer so it's clear to Django what you want to do.

Comment: Good point! I would like to just match a Test to an already existing process, so not create it. I basically just want to provide an existing foreign key with ``process_id``. I will try creating an update method, but it sounds rather cumbersome.

Comment: @ThorbenCroisé Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I would give a serializer like this. One serializer field for read_only where it uses ProcessSerializer and process_id for write_only as integer.

```py
class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    process = ProcessSerializer(read_only=True)
    process_id = IntegerField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ConfigurationTest
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'process',
            'process_id',
        ]
```

And POST this:

```
{
  process_id: 1
  name: 'A new test'
}
```

I am not 100% sure you don't need to override create/update but this should work fine.

N.B.:
I see that you tried something with similar logic. Was it the same code though ?

Comment: Thank you, I was facing a problem for one day and this helped me. Thank you